# Allure report using Newman

Tags: rest, report, postman, allure, newman

I use "newman" to run API tests on Jenkins server. It's very easy for me, I write test scripts in "Postman" and run my collection in "newman" but I can't provide good reports for my manager. I found "allure report" and I like it. Is there any chance to create allure report if I use "Newman". Does allure support newman?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like no, it's impossible.

Why now (after writed tests) you are looking for report tool? It's activity happen in start automation process when qa team analyze test tools are could be used for automation.

I have a look on https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman and think could you try parse commandline output to text file? And use this output to generate simple-report for manager.

Comment: Why it's impossible? After run newman generates junit xml report. Can I use allure to create report based on that junit xml file?

Comment: for creation report allure tool use allure-results after tests. Is the way to build allure into your project for generate allure-results directory? Maven, gradle, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Follow below steps:

```
we can generate nice and clean report using Allure-js framework.
1. Installation
$ npm install -g newman-reporter-allure
    
2. Run the newman cli command to generate Allure results, specify allure in Newman's -r or --reporters option.
$ newman run <Collection> -e <Environment> -r allure

3. Allure results will be generated under folder "allure-results" in the root location. Use allure-commandline to serve the report locally.
$ allure serve

4. To generate the static report web-application folder using allure-commandline
    $ allure generate --clean
Report will be generated under folder "allure-report" in the root location
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use my [repository](https://github.com/igoodkit/postman_via_cli), here's tricky solution, which covers everything:

And add couple more things:

1. Add 2 files: collection *.json and env *.json
2. Add +x permissions to start.sh file with chmod command, like chmod +x start.sh
3. And run script ./start.sh your_collection.json your_env.json

Finally, you will get 2 reports:

- HTML report
- Allure report